# GE Gas stove faulty rubber on regulator, can I repair this with teflon or pipe-dope?

Tags: pipe, gas

I woke up this morning to a gas smell, and after using a gas detector I narrowed the leak down to a poorly fit rubber on the pressure regulator of my stove.

After removing the top screw I see that this rubber is very warped, and around one edge it isn't even making contact with the fittings. I attempted to squeeze the rubber but it doesn't.

[image: Pressure regulator]

This is the regulator I have, that red cap on the left is the rubber that is malformed, it covers a 1/4 inch fitting, the fitting in question. Can I use dope or another substance to fill this or do I need a replacement rubber?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use hacks to fix gas fittings.

Report the damage/defect to GE and your gas authority, and get a proper replacement.

Comment: I think the red cap protects the pressure relief valve.  A bulging cap and the smell of gas would both indicate you had (or still have!) an abnormal high pressure in your gas system or that the regulator is faulty.  If you have utility-supplied gas, do what this answer says -- call BOTH GE and the gas company.  If you have propane call your supplier and/or plumber.  If possible you should also turn off your main gas supply valve until you know what happened.

Comment: @jay613 My plumber says odds are it's bypassing the diaphram, so it's faulty. Thanks for the comments and insights.